# if statement to show image when variable value is higher then 0

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have this few line of codes to show a 'badge'. If a user has earned one badge I manually put the number in the database column `idea_badge` in the user profile table.

So in my view I have these lines of code to show the amount of badges:

```
<a style="font-weight:bold; font-family: Roboto-Black!important; ">
IDEA BADGES:&nbsp;</a>
<?= $user_info['idea_badge']?>
```

This works just fine.

Now I want to echo the badge image. I thought I can make it like this: 
if the number in the database is higher then 0 echo the src...

So for that I made this piece of code:

```
<?php
    $idea_badge = ['idea_badge'];
    if ($idea_badge > 0) {
       print '<img style="width: 30px; height:30px;" src="http://mywebsite.com/photo/new/badge.svg" border=0>'; 
    }

?>
```

I don't get any errors on my view. But it seems like it only prints the image
and doesn't do anything with the `if` statement.

Can you help me make this statement working?

Comment: maybe $idea_badge = $user_info['idea_badge']; ?

Comment: check using debug what you get in $idea_badge

Answer (score 1):

the error is here

```
   $idea_badge = ['idea_badge'];
```

because $idea_badge always true
then

```
 $idea_badge > 0 // is true
```

you have put

```
 $user_info['idea_badge']
```